An after-class exercise of Graph Theory about Classmates' acquaintance.
I'm a CS student on the second grade. Here is the question after the section "Connectivity and Traversal" from my textbook called Graph Theory & Algorithms written by my CS teacher:
If indirect acquaintance is also considered acquaintance, then two people "knowing" each other can be defined as follows: they know each other directly, or they know the same person. Based on this definition: answer the following questions:
Among n classmates, there are only 2 of them that the number of other classmates they know respectively is an odd number. Do these two classmates know each other?
I have some thoughts but it's hard to describe using some mathematical or formalized language. I try to put them down. At first, we need to use graph to model or abstract this question. So we use vertexes in graph to represent the classmates. If two classmates know each other directly, then there is an edge incident with both of the vertexes in graph. If they know each other indirectly, the two vertexes in graph representing them are connected. We named the two students in question u and v. I guess that the two people know each other. Then assume to the contradiction that they don't know each other, then there are two connected components of this graph. One of them contains u, and the other contains v. Then we need to prove it is not possible because it can't guarantee the remaining n - 2 vertexes' degree numbers are all even. How to prove it formalized? Help!Or you can give your verification, not necessarily follow mine.
This problem can also be describe as "Prove or disprove,if u and v are the only vertices of odd degree in a graph G, then G contains a u,v-path."

Hint: if you know an odd number of people, then the size of your connected component is even, so everyone you know also knows an odd number of people.

I'm unclear on the definition; if the graph is A-B-C-D, would you say that A knows D or not? (If yes, then Karl's hint is almost an answer)

If the graph is A-B-C-D, A knows D.

The size of the connected component is not clear. We only know that there are odd vertexes adjacent to u or v.

Thank you for your applies! I still need more helpful suggestions.

Maybe to understand the connected component comment, you should draw some small graphs and see how many people you can get to know an odd number of others.

Thank you for your  applies, but I still can't get its point.

@Karl There are an odd number people directly adjacent to u or v, denoted by u_1, u_2, u_{2k + 1}, but there are possibly still other people adjacent to the 2k + 1 vertexes. Do you mean that if the size of then connected component is even, then that's the contradiction.

@Milten If the graph is A-B-C-D, then A knows D.

Each connected component is a complete graph, so if I know exactly $n$ people, then each of them also knows exactly $n$ people (including me).

@Karl Sorry, I still don't understand. But connected component is not necessarily complete graph.

@Karl Thank you very much, I understand!

@advance The problem states "only 2 of them that the number of other classmates they know respectively is an odd number". According to your definition, this doesn't mean that they are directly adjacent, but only that they "know" each other, i.e. that they are in the same connected component. If this is not your intent with the problem, please clarify. Did you actually mean that there are only 2 people with and odd number of directly adjacent neighbors? This would change the problem quite a lot.

@Milten Sorry, it's my fault. That's exactly what I mean. Thank you so much!

@advance Thanks for the clarification. Hint: there is a simple property about the sum of the degrees of all vertices in a graph; do you know what it is? This property is also true for each connected component viewed in isolation (since a connected component is a graph in its own right)
